# Fundamental theorem of calculus assignment.

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I solve this assignment? The official solution is $y=\frac{(x-1)^2}{36}$. But as it was pointed out, it is incorrect, so I have no idea, how to get the correct one.

Find all non-negative twice continuously differentiable functions $y$ on $[1,\infty)$, which fulfil $y(1)=y'(1)=0$, and for $x_0\in [1,\infty)$,  $(y'(x_0))^2$ equals the area between the graph of $y$ and $x$-axis above $[1,x_0]$.

I have come to the point, where I have $2y'(x)y''(x)=y(x)$, but do not know, how to continue.

This assignment is in the chapter: Integral as a function of upper limit (Fundamental theorem of calculus).

Comment: I supose $\;y'(1)\;$ means *right derivative* ? Also, what do you exactly mean by " for $x_0\in [1,\infty)$,  $(y'(x_0))^2$ equals the area of $y$ and $x$-axis above $[1,x_0]$" ? Is it "the area **between the graph of** $\;y\;$ and the $\;x-$ axis..."?

Comment: @Joanpemo It isn't specified, but I guess so, yes. And yes, it means the area in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the official solution. It must be $y=\frac{(x-1)^3}{36}$

The way to find it without knowing is pretty straightforward: differentiate the requirement and solve the resulting equation:

The requirement is

$${y'}^2 = \int_1^x y(t) dt$$

A fundamental theorem hints to differentiate it:

$$2y'y'' = y$$

Now the only trick is to multiply both sides by $y'$:
$$2{y'}^2y'' = yy'$$

The last equation is easy to integrate (notice complete derivatives):

$$\frac{2}{3}{y'}^3 = \frac{1}{2}y^2 + C$$

An initial condition $y(1) = y'(1) = 0$ mandates that $C = 0$, and you end up with

$$\frac{2}{3}{y'}^3 = \frac{1}{2}y^2$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$(y'(x_0))^2 = \int_1^{x_0} y(t) dt$

Suppose $y=\frac{(x-1)^2}{36}\\y'(x) = \frac{(x-1)}{18}\\(y'(x_0))^2 = \frac{(x_0-1)^2}{324}$

While, $\int_1^{x_0} y(t) dt=\frac{(x_0-1)^3}{54}$

I think something has been mistranslated.

Comment: Thank you for noticing. But that is the official solution. And I have structured the assignment same as you, so I guess that the professor made a mistake (he has a habit of doing it). Do you have any idea, how to solve it, if you don't look at the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The condition "$(y'(x_0))^2$ equals the area between y and the x-axis between 1 and $x_0$" means that $(y'(x))^2= \int_1^{x} y(t)dt$.  Differentiating both sides with respect to x, that is the same as $2y'(x)y''(x)= y(x)$.  If $y= (x- 1)^2/36$ then $y'= (x- 1)/18$ and $y''= 1/18$.  So $2y'(x)y''(x)= 2(x-1)/18(1/18)= (x-1)/162$ NOT $y= (x- 1)^2/36$.

Comment: Thank you for that. I have edited my questions, so that it includes the fact, that the official solution is incorrect. But I still do not know, how to get the right solution (whatever it is).